When are the complex points of a scheme an analytic manifold/space
Original Question: Let $X$ be a regular, projective, flat scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $X(\mathbb{C}$) be the set of complex points of $X$. Why is $X(\mathbb{C}$) a complex analytic manifold? I am familiar with analytic spaces associated to schemes, so my first guess was that one considered $X$ under base change to $\mathbb{C}$ and looked at the associated analytic space. Yet, I do not think this is what the author intended, so I think I am missing something here. I have seen this fact cited before as well, but I cannot find a proof of it and have asked a few people. Any help would be much appreciated.
More general question: What conditions on $X$ above guarantee $X(\mathbb{C}$) to be a complex analytic manifold (or smooth manifold or any other nice property for that matter if such things are known)? I know schemes of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$ have nice properties since we can glue together all of our affine schemes which are just zeros of polynomial functions. However, I don't know what to do if (1) we are not over $\mathbb{C}$ and (2) if our structure morphism is not of finite type.
Thank you for any help!
Edit: I guess the main question now is what conditions guarantee a scheme $X$ over some number field $K$ will be of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$ after base change. Obviously we have projectivity giving us this, but can we weaken it?

Why do you think that it is not the complex analytic space associated with the base change of $X$ to $\mathbb{C}$? That seems to me like the obvious interpretation.

I guess that is the most obvious thing to consider. I didn't really notice projectivity of $X$ guarantees it is of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$, so this actually makes sense! Thank you for the confirmation!

Regarding the general question, $X$ finite type and separated will make $X(\mathbb{C})$ into an analytic space, add smoothness if you want a complex manifold.

The $\mathbf C$-points of $X$ and $X \times_{\operatorname{Spec} \mathbf Z} \operatorname{Spec} \mathbf C$ agree by the universal property of the fibre product (if the latter is viewed as $\mathbf C$-scheme rather than as abstract scheme). The only thing you need is that the generic fibre $X \times_{\operatorname{Spec} \mathbf Z} \operatorname{Spec} \mathbf Q$ is of finite type and regular (equivalently, smooth).

Btw, if $K \to L$ is a field extension, then a $K$-scheme $X$ is of finite type if and only if $X_L$ is of finite type over $\operatorname{Spec} L$. The backwards implication is less trivial; see for instance Tag 02KZ. So this allows you to pass from $K$ to $\mathbf C$ and back (but not back from $\mathbf Q$ to $\mathbf Z$ because the former only sees the generic fibre — it does not tell you about finite generation of the other fibres).

You refer to "what the author intended." What author? Or, rather, of what paper?

@LSpice I was referring to Soulé in this link he mentions it in section 2.3 in the first paragraph. I glossed over the detail at first, but upon reading again, I noticed I didn't actually understand what he was meaning.

Specifically, Soulé says, "Let $X$ be a regular, projective, flat scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$/ We denote $X(\mathbb{C})$ the set of complex points of $X$; it is an analytic manifold." His calling it an analytic manifold not an analytic space threw me off at first.
